# Time getJulianDay() deprecated which alternatives to convert date to julian and vice versa?

Tags: java, android, deprecated, julian-date

I want to use GregorianCalendar instead of Time class, how android documentation suggest, but how manage julian day for store a date as a int in my sqlLite db?

How can i convert this code?

```
   public static long normalizeDate(long startDate) {
    // normalize the start date to the beginning of the (UTC) day
    Time time = new Time();
    time.set(startDate);
    int julianDay = Time.getJulianDay(startDate, time.gmtoff);
    return time.setJulianDay(julianDay);
}
```

And when i query a row how can get the normal date by julian day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>If you simply need to transform a date into an integer to save in a database, you can transform a Date into a String with a SimpleDateFormatter and then cast the string to an int. Something like:</s>

```
Date date = new Date(startDate);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String dateString = formatter.format(date);
int dateInt = Integer.parseInt(dateString);
```

That would create an integer you can easily save and retrieve in a database.

You should use a code similar to:

```
public static long normalizeDate(long startDate) {
    // normalize the start date to the beginning of the (UTC) day
    GregorianCalendar date = (GregorianCalendar)     GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    date.setTime(new Date(startDate));
    date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)

    //transform your calendar to a long in the way you prefer
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andrea but I need a solution that does not consider the timezone

Comment: @FedericoPonti I have updated my answer, it should now do what you need.