# Time.getJulianDay() deprecated. Which code would get the work done instead?

Tags: java, android, deprecated

Since Time class is deprecated, I can no longer use the getJulianDay() in the following function. I want to use Calender or GregorianCalender class to achieve the same. I partly got my answer from [question]:[Time getJulianDay() deprecated which alternatives to convert date to julian and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200970/time-getjulianday-deprecated-which-alternatives-to-convert-date-to-julian-and/33202431#33202431)
but I'm new to such classes so I don't know how to transform the GregorianCalender to long so that I can return it in the function. How can I get the Julian Date? Thanks!

```
public static long normalizeDate(long startDate) {
    // normalize the start date to the beginning of the (UTC) day
    Time time = new Time();
    time.set(startDate);
    int julianDay = Time.getJulianDay(startDate, time.gmtoff);
    return time.setJulianDay(julianDay);
}
```

Comment: There are [lots of questions and answers on SO](/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+julian+date) about Julian dates. What about them is unhelpful? For instance, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035403/julian-date-to-regular-date-conversion)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this suits what you need?

```
public static long normalizeDate(long startDate) {
    // normalize the start date to the beginning of the (UTC) day
    GregorianCalendar date = (GregorianCalendar)     GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    date.setTime(new Date(startDate));
    date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    //transform your calendar to a long in the way you prefer
    return date.getTimeInMillis();
}
```